# Ubuntu 12.10 not recognized after installing Windows 8

Tags: boot, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I used to dual boot Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell XPS 15, now I installed Windows 8 Pro and now Ubuntu does not appear during Boot.
There was a similar question asked in some other forum and the solution suggested was to boot with the ubuntu CD.
I did the same and tried to boot with the CD , I get the error that `No Operating system found` and Windows 8 loads again.

I will be really grateful if someone can suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just boot from live usb/disk and reinstall grub
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks it worked, I downloaded the Boot-Repair Disk and burned it onto a usb stick and chose to boot from it and now everything works perfectly